# 2 region on graph with power law on gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to know if I can make 2 power law on same data on gnuplot. I have 2 regions on my graphic and want both power law. I know how to make on xmgrace, but I dont like the final art from xmgrace, and I want to make a epslatex of this figure. All time I try to do the power law its start at zero, in both regions, on xmgrace I can make the up power low start at that region, like this

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdyjm1c36evi1ph/Global.eps?dl=0

EDIT: I post all data here now.

This is my data.

```
0.000000 0.000180
0.002000 0.000180
0.004000 0.000180
0.006000 0.000360
0.008000 0.000240
0.010000 0.000360
0.012000 0.000420
0.014000 0.000480
0.016000 0.000540
0.018000 0.000720
0.020000 0.000660
0.022000 0.000840
0.024000 0.000960
0.026000 0.001080
0.028000 0.001200
0.030000 0.001320
0.032000 0.001320
0.034000 0.001500
0.036000 0.001560
0.038000 0.001740
0.040000 0.001800
0.042000 0.002040
0.044000 0.002040
0.046000 0.002400
0.048000 0.002460
0.050000 0.002340
0.052000 0.002640
0.054000 0.002700
0.056000 0.002760
0.058000 0.002940
0.060000 0.002760
0.062000 0.002940
0.064000 0.003180
0.066000 0.003000
0.068000 0.003180
0.070000 0.003120
0.072000 0.003120
0.074000 0.003060
0.076000 0.003120
0.078000 0.003180
0.080000 0.003300
0.082000 0.003120
0.084000 0.003180
0.086000 0.003300
0.088000 0.003300
0.090000 0.003300
0.092000 0.003420
0.094000 0.003300
0.096000 0.003480
0.098000 0.003420
0.100000 0.003540
0.102000 0.003360
0.104000 0.003360
0.106000 0.003540
0.108000 0.003480
0.110000 0.003540
0.112000 0.003360
0.114000 0.003540
0.116000 0.003420
0.118000 0.003480
0.120000 0.003420
0.122000 0.003600
0.124000 0.003480
0.126000 0.003480
0.128000 0.003900
0.130000 0.003540
0.132000 0.003900
0.134000 0.003600
0.136000 0.003720
0.138000 0.003780
0.140000 0.003660
0.142000 0.003720
0.144000 0.003780
0.146000 0.003660
0.148000 0.003720
0.150000 0.003900
0.152000 0.003780
0.154000 0.003840
0.156000 0.003960
0.158000 0.003900
0.160000 0.003900
0.162000 0.003840
0.164000 0.003960
0.166000 0.004020
0.168000 0.003960
0.170000 0.004140
0.172000 0.004020
0.174000 0.004020
0.176000 0.004140
0.178000 0.004080
0.180000 0.004020
0.182000 0.004020
0.184000 0.004200
0.186000 0.004200
0.188000 0.004200
0.190000 0.004260
0.192000 0.004320
0.194000 0.004080
0.196000 0.004200
0.198000 0.004140
```

On gnuplot i separate the data in 2 data. Saw where start each region, and do

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set output "powerlaw.eps"
set ylabel "{/Symbol D}{/Symbol w}"
set xlabel "d"
set logscale x
set logscale y
f(x) = a*x**b
g(x) = c*x**d
h(x) = x < 0.057 ? f(x) : g(x)
fit h(x) 'data.dat' u 1:2 via a,b,c,d
pl "data.dat" w p tittle "", h(x)
```

them i got for a,b,c,d

```
a               = 0.0898041        +/- 0.3695       (411.4%)
b               = 1.20131          +/- 1.299        (108.2%)
c               = -0.626148        +/- 2.368e+19    (3.782e+21%)
d               = 28.5183          +/- 2.372e+19    (8.316e+19%)
```

EDIT:10/01/2015
i found a solution but dont know why, I change the code for

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set output "powerlaw.eps"
set ylabel "{/Symbol D}{/Symbol w}"
set xlabel "d"
set logscale x
set logscale y
f(x) = a*x**b+e
g(x) = c*x**d+f
h(x) = x < 0.057 ? f(x) : g(x)
fit h(x) 'data.dat' u 1:2 via a,b,c,d,e,f
pl "data.dat" w p, h(x)
```

with this i got

```
a               = 0.156195         +/- 0.03023      (19.35%)
b               = 1.40894          +/- 0.0678       (4.812%)
c               = 0.00781003       +/- 0.00111      (14.21%)
d               = 0.803641         +/- 0.1621       (20.17%)
e               = 0.000178048      +/- 4.158e-05    (23.35%)
f               = 0.00217076       +/- 0.0002812    (12.95%)
```

see the difference for c and d? And e f is almost zero.

Thanks with help.

Comment: I cant visit your links because I'm behind the Great Fire Wall (I'm in China. embarrassed~~~). Maybe you can try the second axis of gnuplot. For example, `plot sin(x) axis x1y1, 100*sin(10*x) axis x2y2`

Comment: Please include the script which you have now.

Comment: Try to set xrange before each `fit` and `plot` command. I don't know whether it will work, but you can try.

Answer (score 0):

I still can't access your data because I'm behind the Great Fire Wall. But as I discern from your script, I can guess what you want.

Now I audaciously post my solution:

Firstly, define a ternary function `h(x) = x < num ? f(x) : g(x)`

Then fit the data with h(x): `fit h(x) 'data.dat' via a,b,c,d`

Finally, plot the data and h(x): `plot 'data.dat' w p, h(x)`

[image]

Comment: The figure you can acess or both you cant? Know how i could post this for you can see?

Comment: Neither. Do you have permissions to post figure in your question?

Comment: Nope, need at least 10 rep.

Comment: The second region start at around x=0.06, with what do you say o got only the power law for the first region, second one nope, the region above 0.06.

Comment: I generate a data set and then fit and plot it. I post the figure in my answer. You can chech it whether it's what you want.

Comment: You can post you script please? For me he make a fit for second region, but with wrong values.

Comment: I Edit the post posting all data, so you can see it now @DragonHu. ;)